# Javascript - rowIndex for button not working in table

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code where I am trying to change the content of the first cell in `table2` to the text in `table1` using DOM/Javascript:

I have researched the previous questions on SO, including using `this` keyword to pass the rowIndex value but these are not working. I'd appreciate if someone can help me.

```js
function getmylocation() {
  var Row = document.getElementById('table1');
  var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var RowToChange = document.getElementById('table2');
  var CellsToChange = RowToChange.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  CellsToChange[0].innerText = Cells[this.rowIndex].innerText;
}
```

```html
<table id='table1'>
  <tr>
    <td> row1, col1</td>
    <td> <button onclick='getmylocation();'>Click</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> row2, col1</td>
    <td> <button onclick='getmylocation();'>Click</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table id='table2'>
  <tr>
    <td> empty1</td>
    <td>empty2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: As per Mate's answer, what worked is to use `getmylocation.call(this)` instead.

Comment: I posted my answer for finding the table row, but I should also ask: the `rowIndex` property might not even be the one you want to use. `rowIndex`, as the name suggests, contains the number of the row within the table. You say you want to copy the contents of a *cell*, so maybe you're looking for `cellIndex` instead? In that case, you'll want to find the closes `<td>` element to the `<button>`, not `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getmylocation()` is invoked as a method of the `<button>`. Buttons don't have a `rowIndex` property, table rows do. Meaning, you have to find the `<tr>` that your button resides in. Here are some options:

**1. The quick and dirty way**

```
var MyRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
```

This isn't really recommended, since this assumes that the "grandparent" of the `<button>` is the `<tr>`. If you put the `<button>` inside any element, such as a `<span>` within the table cell, this will break.

**2. The elegant way**

```
var MyRow = this.closest('tr');
```

The `closest()` method was introduced fairly recently, and it can be used to find the closest ancestor of an element that matches the passed CSS selector (in this case, `'tr'`). This method is not supported on older browsers, though, so you need to know your target audience (cf: https://caniuse.com/#search=closest).

**3. The in-between way**

```
var MyRow = this;
while (MyRow.tagName !== 'TR') {
    MyRow = MyRow.parentNode;
}
```

This is basically you implementing a limited version of `closest()`: you start with the `<button>` element where the click was triggered, and cycle through its ancestors until you find the first one whose `tagName` property is `TR`. Be careful: JavaScript is case-sensitive, and as you can see, the `tagName` property is always in all-caps, even if you wrote your HTML code in lowercase.

Comment: Hi Máté, sorry, I tried putting your options 1-3 separately in the `getmylocation()` function and in both Opera and Firefox (updated to the latest release), they do not work. In the console, it seems `this` is not defined: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined   at getmylocation`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try writing the button this way: `<button onclick='getmylocation.call(this);'>` - This will set the value of `this` inside `getmylocation` to the button that was clicked. You might also want to read up some more about event handler functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Thank you, it works now. Is it acceptable to mark this answer as accepted and edit my original question with the working code to help other people in the future?

Comment: Sure, just add a note at the bottom about how you changed it in the end.